# My account creation program doesn't validate the inputs after the first validation, is there a much more efficient way of doing it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, account, user-accounts

My program consists of a menu prompted to the user that asks them whether they would like to sign up, log in or exit. Right now, I am working on the signing up part, It asks for a username input from the user and it should ensure that the username is between 3-16 characters long, isn't already being used and consists of only these characters: A-Za-z0-9_    The issue here is that it validates once and has some sort of bug that ignores validating if the length of the username is less than 3 or more than 16 or has a special character but it is fine with checking whether the username is already used or not. After the username input it asks the user for a password input and that seems to work fine. After all the inputs, it adds the username and password to a txt database that is stored on the computer. If there is a much more efficient way of doing this, please let me know, it would be appreciated.

Here is the program:

```
import sys, re, csv
usernamecheck = False
charcheck = False
menu = int(input("1. Sign Up\n2. Log in\n3. Exit"))
menu_numbers = (1,2,3)
while menu not in menu_numbers:
    menu = int(input("1. Sign Up\n2. Log in\n3. Exit"))
if menu == 1:
        newusername = input("Input a new username: ")
        if (not re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9_]*$", newusername)) or len(newusername)<3 or len(newusername)>16:
                firstusernamevalidation = False
                print("Username length is either less than 3 or more than 16 or has special characters.")
        else:
                firstusernamevalidation = True
        with open('accountdatabase.txt', mode = 'r') as file:
                reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
                for line in file:
                        if newusername == line.split(',')[0]:
                                secondusernamevalidation = False
                                print("Username is taken, try another one.")
                        else:
                                secondusernamevalidation = True
        while firstusernamevalidation and secondusernamevalidation == False:
                newusername = input("Input another username: ")
                if (not re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9_]*$", newusername)) or len(newusername)<3 or len(newusername)>16:
                        firstusernamevalidation = False
                        print("Username length is either less than 3 or more than 16 or has special characters.")
                else:
                        firstusernamevalidation = True
                with open('accountdatabase.txt', mode = 'r') as file:
                        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
                        for line in file:
                                if newusername == line.split(',')[0]:
                                        secondusernamevalidation = False
                                        print("Username is taken, try another one.")
                                else:
                                        secondusernamevalidation = True
        newpassword = input("Input a password: ")
        while len(newpassword)<8:
               newpassword = input("Input a password that has 8 or more characters: ")
        validatepassword = input("Input the same password: ")
        while newpassword != validatepassword:
                newpassword = input("Input a password: ")
                while len(newpassword)<8:
                        newpassword = input("Input a password that has 8 or more characters: ")
                validatepassword = input("Input the same password: ")
        with open('accountdatabase.txt', mode = 'a') as file:
                file.write(str(newusername) + "," + str(newpassword))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `or` works so, that if the first condition returns `True` it won't check the other ones, it will just continue the code. so what you would need to change is that instead of using `or` you should use `and`.

Or the easier way is to let the regular expression check the length like in this function:

```py
from re import match

def isUsernameValid(username):
    isValid = match(r"^[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,16}$", username)
    if isValid:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

good luck stranger!